# Showing MessageDialogs one after another in WindowsStoreApps using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, messagedialog

In WindowsStoreApps I have three MessageDialogs which have to be showed one bye one by clicking a button in each MessageDialog.While doing this I get an 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'.It seems we cant open another messageDialog while one is open.Is there a possiblity to close the previous dialog while opening the next one? or Can any one suggest me an idea how to handle this issue.

```
 MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Have you been enjoying your experience with " + Modules.Title + " ?");              
            UICommand btn_ntreally = new UICommand("Not Really");
            md.Commands.Add(btn_ntreally);
            btn_ntreally.Invoked += btn_ntreally_invoked;
            UICommand btn_yeah = new UICommand("Yeah!");
            md.Commands.Add(btn_yeah);
            btn_yeah.Invoked += btn_yeah_invoked;
            md.ShowAsync();
```

I get system.unauthorised exception messagedialog.showasync.

```
private async void btn_yeah_invoked(IUICommand command)
    {
      MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Deal is deal");

      UICommand btn_Sure_invoked = new UICommand("Sure");
      md.Commands.Add(btn_Sure_invoked);
      btn_ntreally.Invoked += btn_Sure_invoked;

      UICommand btn_yeah = new UICommand("No thanks!");
      md.Commands.Add(btn_tnks);

      await md.ShowAsync(); //getting system.UnauthorizedAccessException here           
    }

    private async void btn_Sure_invoked(IUICommand command)
    {
        UICommand btn_rateAppsure = new UICommand("Yes!");
        md.Commands.Add(btn_rateAppsure);
        btn_rateAppsure.Invoked += btn_rateAppsure_invoked;

        UICommand btn_rateNothanks = new UICommand("No.Thanks");
        md.Commands.Add(btn_rateNothanks);

        await md.ShowAsync(); //getting system.UnauthorizedAccessException here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The MessageDialog is intended to block all other activities in your app and force the user to respond to the action your request from him. So it doesn't seem logical to fire 3 messagedialogs at the same time. That's most likely the reason your getting the exception.

Because your code sample isn't that clear about what you're trying to achieve with the 3 messagedialogs, I'll come up with some approaches that you might like:

**1**
Show a custom kind of message dialog where you use viewstates to differentiate the different questions that the user has to answer before he can continue.

**2**
Show a messagedialog where all 3 questions are shown and multiple buttons to answer the variants?

The last one isn't the nicest solution. If you eloborate a bit on what you exactly trying to achieve maybe we can come up with some better solutions to fix your problem.

Comment: Hello ChristiaanV,I dont need to show three dialogs at a time,but one after another buy clicking the button in messageDialog.Is there a possiblity to close the previous dialog while opening the next one?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this use this pattern (which I don't really recommend), you can set a timer to call you some time after the dialog has been closed, and then you will be able to call another dialog to open.

Comment: Hello ArielBH,Is there any possibility to close the dialog programatically?